# Spring 4 / Spring social - PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I'm following this example to integrate Spring Social with JWT (stateless).

http://blog.jdriven.com/2015/01/stateless-spring-security-part-3-jwt-social-authentication/

Here's my spring log output

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter- Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@25ef2346
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Request is to process authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Authentication request failed: org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationRedirectException: 
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFailureHandler@65dea49
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook?code=AQAFgopGOJzTCdj---j8cN5GqdsmhpKuD0Yinu-&state=586d5c06-d2ec-484d-a430-8ebff2900e05 at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter- Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@25ef2346
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook?code=AQAFgopGOJzTCdj-KER50kXm8lkxQTdqYlOuxcFwiDcCssw29Wp--j8cN5GqdsmhpKuD0Yinu-&state=586d5c06-d2ec-484d-a430-8ebff2900e05 at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /auth/facebook?code=-KER50kXm8lkxQTdqYlOuxcFwiDcCssw29Wp---&state=586d5c06-d2ec-484d-a430-8ebff2900e05 at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Request is to process authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Created POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token"
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Setting request Accept header to [application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/json, application/*+json]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Writing [{client_id=[119076044790683], client_secret=[49f4fadf74a562b6312eb0332be5b14e], code=[----], redirect_uri=[http://havefunhub.com:8081/api/auth/facebook], grant_type=[authorization_code]}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter@5b7cf920]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token" resulted in 200 (OK)
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Reading [interface java.util.Map] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2448c6a1]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Created GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Clink"
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Clink" resulted in 200 (OK)
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- Reading [class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@784acd1f]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager- Authentication attempt using org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate- Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate- Executing prepared SQL statement [select userId from UserConnection where providerId = ? and providerUserId = ?]
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils- Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource- Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/havefun?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8]
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils- Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager- Requesting to create or join a transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler- Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource- Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/havefun?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8]
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils- Closing JPA EntityManager
DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager- Rollback requested: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/35, status: OPEN
DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager- Rollback invoked
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: user not found
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter- Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFailureHandler@65dea49
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler- Redirecting to /signin
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy- Redirecting to '/api/signin'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter- Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@25ef2346
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter- Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa86552: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 261DFFE68998DB03A0CEC795038D4263; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/favicon.ico'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/auth/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Request 'GET /signin' doesn't match 'POST /subscriptions/**
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Request 'GET /signin' doesn't match 'POST /verifications/**
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/graph/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher- Request '/signin' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor- Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /signin; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor- Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa86552: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 261DFFE68998DB03A0CEC795038D4263; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased- Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@41f8b39, returned: 1
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor- Authorization successful
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor- RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy- /signin reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet- DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/api/signin]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping- Looking up handler method for path /signin
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping- Did not find handler method for [/signin]
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/signin] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet- Successfully completed request
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter- Chain processed normally
```

The line that tells me something in the log is

**WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/signin] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**

This is my java configuration

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.setDisplayName("HaveFunHub Public API");

        //load profile dependent properties
        loadProfileProperties(ctx);

        ctx.scan("com.havefunhub.api.config", "com.havefunhub.api.security.config");

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", CORSFilter.class);
        corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        corsFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet1 = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet1.addMapping("/");
        servlet1.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet1.setAsyncSupported(true);


        DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain", ctx);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurity = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
                springSecurityFilterChain);
        springSecurity.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
        springSecurity.setAsyncSupported(true);

        //required for neo4j scoped bean session
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
```

This is my security java configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Set a custom successHandler on the SocialAuthenticationFilter
        final SpringSocialConfigurer socialConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        socialConfigurer.addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
            @Override
            public <O extends SocialAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O socialAuthenticationFilter) {
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setAlwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);

                socialAuthenticationFilter.setPostLoginUrl(environment.getProperty("login.welcome.screen"));
                System.out.println("socialConfigurer that adds SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain is created and configured with socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler");
                logger.info("socialConfigurer that adds SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain is created and configured with socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler");
                return socialAuthenticationFilter;
            }
        });
      //add custom authentication filter for complete stateless JWT based authentication
                    .addFilterBefore(statelessAuthenticationFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)

                    //apply the configuration from the socialConfigurer (adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter)
                    .apply(socialConfigurer.userIdSource(userIdSource));
```

I have it all working before but after some changes it stopped working. I can't really tell which change was but the more important was the introduction of Neo4j (using spring-data repositories).

I can't work out where to configure the link between the requested URL and the controller which handles it that is part of spring social.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was due to inconsistency in DB. User was deleted from 'user' table but its corresponding 'UserConnection' row (spring social creates a row in that table for each provider) was still there. After deleting all, it cleared the problem.